# Github: Create a README file remotely, will not pull down to local repo

Tags: git, github, git-pull, git-extensions

I noticed while browsing a repo on the Github website that there wasn't a `Readme.md` file, and Github suggested I make one.  So I did.

After adding the `Readme.md` file in the web interface, with a commit to a `dev` branch, I came back to my local repo to pull the Readme down and update to include the latest commit.  I did have some changes in the `working directory`, but nothing in `index`.  I needed to change from a different branch, so I stashed the changes and did a checkout on `dev`. In Git Extensions I could see the remote `origin/dev` branch one commit ahead, so I ran a git pull to fastforward to the `Readme.md` commit.  Which all seemed to work.

However, at this point I noticed an issue - a `git status` shows:

> deleted: README.md

So, git knows there is supposed to be a `README.md` with this commit, but it isn't in the working directory. I checked the wd with windows explorer, and `README.md` is not in the root directory.  I checked back on Github, and it's there.  I looked in the "File tree" in Git Extensions, and it's also there. But it's not physically on the computer in the folder, and git knows it's not there. I reran `git pull` and `git fetch` and tried reading the `git fetch --help` and `git pull --help` man pages, and tried a few commands, but nothing will pull down the `README.md` that I can find.

### Question: How do I pull down the file that was added remotely?

I could manually download the file and physically place it in the folder, but I want to know how to do this properly.  Extra points for an explanation about what happened.  Thanks!!

Comment: could you post the entire `git status` output?

Comment: @LightBender - thanks for the nudge. Looking back at the git status and thinking through the process it took to get here hit on the solution for me - answer posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue when LightBender asked in a comment for the full git status, and rather than remove the question, I'll post the root cause and solution here.

### Root Cause Discussion

Before checking out `dev` I stashed the changes I had on `master`, but then I unstashed them on `dev`, planning to add them to a new commit after pulling down `README.md` from the remote.

**It turns out the stashing somehow realized that `master` didn't have README.md, so when I applied the stash to `dev` after the `git pull` it actually deleted the file.** Suspecting this, I restashed the changes and the deletion of `README.md` disappeared (from `git status`), and after that a new `git pull` did correctly pull `README.md` down from `origin/dev` into my working directory. I didn't realize that `git stash` will file away deletions as well as additions and changes...

So, the problem came in because I had stashed the changes originally off of `master`, and those changes should not have been unstashed on `dev` in the first place. Being a newbie, I lost track of the flow. It was still good to learn about this behavior for future reference.

### Solution

I was able to simply unstash (not sure the git commands for unstash - I use Git Extensions for that) back on `master`, and then cherry-pick the new `README.md` commit from `dev` onto `master`.